# Python dependencies in AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a lambda using python directly in the console and am stuck on installing a dependency.  Is there a way to install dependencies in the console?  I have tried a subprocess call but says I don't have permission to the folders.

I am used to doing lambdas in javascript and have deploy scripts for that.  I just don't know how to translate that to python.

Comment: What I did was installing all dependencies in a folder called `package` and when deploying, create a zip file with all the `package` contents together with the python function, and then use awscli from terminal to push to the AWS server. This might help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package-create.html

Comment: What script were you using for javascript ?Were you using some framework like Serverless ?

Comment: Lambda supports Docker containers https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html